# About the definition of the contraction of a tensor.

Tags: definition, tensors

According to the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_contraction#Abstract_formulation)...
If I have a tensor $v \otimes f \in V \otimes V^*$, then its contraction would be the $0$-tensor $f(v)$ (scalar)

But if I have $v\otimes w \otimes f \otimes g \in V \otimes V  \otimes V^* \otimes V^*$, would the result of the contraction be

$v \otimes g$ or $f(w) v\otimes g$ ?

Comment: There are many contractions $f(v)(w\otimes g)$, or $f(w)(v\otimes g)$, or $g(v)(w\otimes g)$, or $g(w)(v\otimes f)$, or $f(v)g(w)$, or $f(w)g(v)$. The last two being compositions of two of the previous ones.

Comment: In the last 2 you do a double contraction right? So the contraction $v\otimes g$ doesn't exist right?